# How to keep input accessory view up when presenting view controller

Tags: ios, swift, inputaccessoryview

I have a container view that is set as the input accessory view for my view controller. Whenever I present a modal view controller the input accessory view dismisses.

I tried using the code below which works when I present the modal view controller. However, that view controller presents an image picker controller and after presenting that image picker controller I get the error "Keyboard cannot present view controllers." Is there a way to keep the input accessory view open for any view controllers presented on top of the base view controller.

```
let rootViewController: UIViewController = (UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController)!
rootViewController.present(addVideoController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to keep an `inputAccessoryView` active through the view hierarchy - either pushing the view onto a `navigationController` stack or displaying modally will not keep the root's `inputAccessoryView` visible from my experience. This is because `inputAccessoryView` is a member of the `UIViewController` class rather than the window itself - and the new `UIViewController` you are making active does not have an `inputAccessoryView`.

I believe you will need to add a `inputAccessoryView` into the `UIViewController` class that you are presenting modally. You can set it up the exact same way that you did with the root view controller's class.

```
// call this in your root view controller that has the inputAccessoryView currently displayed
let addViewController = YourViewControllerClass()
modalViewController.inputAccessoryView = self.inputAccessoryView
self.present(addViewController, animated: true, completion: nil))
```